# Select multiple columns with where condition Panda DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like:

> `date, Unnamed: 1, workdate, Unnamed: 3,worknumber, Unnamed: 5,weight, Unnamed: 7....and more`

I want to select the all columns with names Unnamed and drop those columns.
I know how this work in SQL with like % function, but do not have a fair idea how it works in Python with Dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.startswith` and pass the negative of the resulting Boolean array to [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.startswith('Unnamed')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) - `^` is regex for start of string:

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
```